# Deep Freeze stuck in Frozen mode

Tags: windows-10, deep-freeze

I started working at a newly open gaming lounge and I'm trying to make the PC to revert back after clients leave, bla bla bla, the usual story.

Now the problem is, I was trying a more "cheap" solution and I opted for the Reboot Restore Rx software solution, but, the "on the house" clients keep deactivating it (for what reason only god know since it doesn't interfere with games and GPU major updates come only once or twice /month).

So, in order to stop this rebellion I turned to Faronics Deep Freeze.

I got the Enterprise, and after installing it on the main machine and on one station (smart move, otherwise I would be burning the building down) I can't seem to unfreeze it.

I tried accessing it from the PC, select "Boot Thawed", and it reboot back in frozen mode... I tried it at least 7 times. Went to the main admin station, right clicked the station, "Reboot in Thawed Mode", boots back in frozen. I updated the server, tried to send the new updated config to the pc, nothing... I tried the Standard version (on another machine) and this one does the same. Is there a problem with the software?

Is it conflicting with some windows setting? It feels like I'm gonna go nuts and just quit this job, since there is no way in stopping this blockheads to mess with the machines.

Comment: Are there any logs indicating where the issue may be happening?

Comment: Done, apparently just hitting enter once doesn't make a new paragraph :/.
And no, I don't think it leaves any logs behind. I also think it would be pointless since they will be deleted upon reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted cheap why go for Deep Freeze it's much more expensive than Reboot Restore Rx Pro. Are you using Windows 10? If so Deep Freeze has hundreds of known issues with the OS and this is one of them. Would consider trying the demo for Reboot Restore Rx Pro and seeing if that has the same issues. If not I'd consider moving to that.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to a citation of this being a known issue for further reading?